# Clean removal of Python virtual environment

Tags: python, pipenv

I am new to python virtual environments. While trying to remove a virtual enviroment i accidently removed the Pipfile and Pipfile.lock first before using pipenv --rm to remove the virtual environment. Is it safe to remove the corresponding directory in ~/.local/share/virtualenvs.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Usually a Python virtual environment corresponds to a folder named as the environment. So, you could simply delete the folder containing the environment.